Any book recommendation for understanding the development of the notion of culture from paideia to Bildung?
I would like to understand the development of the notion of culture from the Greek paideia to modern Bildung. For this, I would like to read works written by Plato, Aristotle, Hobbes, Rousseau, Kant, Schiller, Schlegel, Hegel, and Comte. However, I don't know which of their works should I read. I was wondering if you can recommend one or two works each from these philosophers.

Paideia and Bildung are usually translated as education rather than culture. Plato's Republic, Aristotle's Politics (book VIII), Rousseau's Emile, or On Education, Kant's Lectures on Pedagogy, Schiller's On the Aesthetic Education of Man, Hegel's Philosophy of Right are some standard sources.

All four essays in Nietzsche's Untimely Meditations (David Strauss: the Confessor and the Writer; On the Use and Abuse of History for Life; Schopenhauer as Educator; Richard Wagner in Bayreuth) taken together give a fascinating lens into Nietzsche's thought on Bildung, education, art, and mistakes thereof. Classical ideals relative to these matters, their past and present, are never far from Nietzsche's work during this period either.

@PaulCanis Do you know other books from Marx and Freud that critizied Bildung?

@Vicky Not expert enough in Marx and for Freud, the classic Civilization and its Discontents is really a work unto itself, especially given the historical context at which it was directed and in the midst of which it was written.
